# XML path aggregation: one subquery for multiple `selects` on same subset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, for-xml-path

When using XML path for aggregation, many times I need different strings which are based on the same set. Consider this example (script at the end):

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| firstname |   thing   |    val     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| mike      | Tesla     |      50000 |
| mike      | Mona Lisa | 3000000000 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

I want this result set returned:

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| firstname |            what_I_say_to_friends            |                         what_I_say_to_finance                          |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Mike      | My friend Mike owns a Tesla and a Mona Lisa | My friend Mike owns a Tesla priced 50000 and a Mona Lisa priced 3e+009 |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I know how to do this using two different xml-path subqueries. But, since the only thing that changes is the choice of data to show (select), and not the underlying rows, is there any way to do it with a single xml path?

Data construction & dual xml query:

```
create table friend (   firstname nvarchar(50) )

insert friend values ('Mike')

create table owns
(
    firstname nvarchar(50)
    ,thing nvarchar(50)
    ,val float
)

insert  owns values
('mike','Tesla',50000),('mike','Mona Lisa',3000000000)

select 
    f.firstname
    ,'My friend '+f.firstname+' owns a '+q1.collection_no_value as what_I_say_to_friends
    ,'My friend '+f.firstname+' owns a '+q2.collection_with_value as what_I_say_to_finance
from 
    friend f
    cross apply
    (
        select 
            stuff
            (
                ( 
                    select ' and a ' + o.thing
                    from owns o
                    where o.firstname=f.firstname
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                ,1,7,''
            ) as collection_no_value
    ) as q1
cross apply
(
    select 
        stuff
        (
            ( 
                    select ' and a ' + o.thing+' priced '+convert(nvarchar(max),val)
                    from owns o
                    where o.firstname=f.firstname
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
            ,1,7, ''
        ) as collection_with_value
) as q2
```

Comment: *"Is there any way to do it with a single xml path?"* In short, no. `FOR XML PATH` is the pre SQL Server 2017 solution to `STRING_AGG`, however, you need to use 1 sub query per aggregation. If you don't want sub queries, you'll need to use `STRING_AGG` on a version of SQL Server that supports it (2017+).

Comment: On a separate note, the fact that your expected output gives `'and a Mona Lisa priced 3e+009'` strongly suggests your column `val` is being stored in a floating point data type (`float`/`real`). This is a really bad idea. Floating point values are *not* accurate values and most certainly should not be used for storing monetary values.

Comment: @Larnu the sample data are totally made up. Usually what I need is column names from sys.tables, and a sister string that also has datatypes

Comment: @Larnu You can avoid requerying the table multiple times though, as shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't quite do this without an extra subquery, but **you can avoid querying the same table again and again.**

All you need to do, is to get the data into a single XML blob in one subquery, then query it back out in each of the other subqueries:

```sql
select 
    f.firstname
    ,'My friend '+f.firstname+' owns a '+q1.collection_no_value as what_I_say_to_friends
    ,'My friend '+f.firstname+' owns a '+q2.collection_with_value as what_I_say_to_finance
from 
    friend f

    cross apply
    (
        select (
            select o.thing, o.price
            from owns o
            where o.firstname = f.firstname
            FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE
        )
    ) x(XmlBlob)

    cross apply
    (
        select 
            stuff
            (
                ( 
                    select ' and a ' + x2.rw.value('(thing/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
                    from x.XmlBlob.nodes('/row') x2(rw)
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
                ,1,7,''
            ) as collection_no_value
    ) as q1
    cross apply
    (
        select 
            stuff
            (
                ( 
                    select ' and a ' + x2.rw.value('(thing/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') + ' priced ' + x2.rw.value('(price/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
                    from x.XmlBlob.nodes('/row') x2(rw)
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
                ,1,7, ''
            ) as collection_with_value
    ) as q2
```

As you can see, it's actually more long-winded. On the other hand, if the subquery to create the blob is very complex then **it may be more performant because the subquery is only executed once.**

---

**You can also achieve the same effect by creating a JSON array**, in SQL Server 2016

```sql
select 
    f.firstname
    ,'My friend '+f.firstname+' owns a '+q1.collection_no_value as what_I_say_to_friends
    ,'My friend '+f.firstname+' owns a '+q2.collection_with_value as what_I_say_to_finance
from 
    friend f

    cross apply
    (
        select (
            select o.thing, o.price
            from owns o
            where o.firstname = f.firstname
            FOR JSON PATH
        )
    ) j(JsonBlob)

    cross apply
    (
        select 
            stuff
            (
                ( 
                    select ' and a ' + JSON_VALUE(j2.value, '$.thing')
                    from OPENJSON(j.JsonBlob) j2
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
                ,1,7,''
            ) as collection_no_value
    ) as q1
    cross apply
    (
        select 
            stuff
            (
                ( 
                    select ' and a ' + JSON_VALUE(j2.value, '$.thing') + ' priced ' + JSON_VALUE(j2.value, '$.price')
                    from OPENJSON(j.JsonBlob) j2
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
                ,1,7, ''
            ) as collection_with_value
    ) as q2
```

---

**Obviously, in SQL Server 2017+ you can just use `STRING_AGG`:**

```sql
select 
    f.firstname
    ,'My friend '+f.firstname+' owns a ' + STRING_AGG(CAST(o.thing AS nvarchar(max)), ' and a ') as what_I_say_to_friends
    ,'My friend '+f.firstname+' owns a ' + STRING_AGG(o.thing + ' priced ' + convert(nvarchar(max), o.price), ' and a ') as what_I_say_to_finance
from 
    friend f
group by f.firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even this way, pure XQuery based.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @owns TABLE (firstname nvarchar(50), thing nvarchar(50), val float);
INSERT  @owns VALUES
('mike','Tesla',50000),
('mike','Mona Lisa',3000000000);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator VARCHAR(10) = ' and a ';
WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT firstname
    , (
       SELECT * 
       FROM @owns AS c
       WHERE c.firstname = p.firstname
       FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
    ) AS xmldata
    FROM @owns AS p
    GROUP BY p.firstname
)
SELECT * 
    , 'My friend ' + firstname + ' owns a ' + xmldata.query('
        for $x in /root/r
        return if ($x is (/root/r[position() = last()])[1]) then string($x/thing[1])
                else concat(($x/thing/text())[1], sql:variable("@separator"))
       ').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS what_I_say_to_friends
    , 'My friend ' + firstname + ' owns a ' + xmldata.query('
        for $x in /root/r
        let $token := concat(string($x/thing[1]), " priced ", string($x/val[1]))
        return if ($x is (/root/r[position() = last()])[1]) then $token
                else concat($token, sql:variable("@separator"))
       ').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS what_I_say_to_finance 
FROM rs;
```